# Upload multiple images one by one using AJAX after click submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, forms, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload multiple images using `ajax` and the `FormData Object`. The problem that I have is that the script only uploads 1 image and does nothing with the others.

This script will be used only in chrome

Here is the script JS:

```
(function () {
    var count = 0;

    function showUploadedItem(source,index) {
        var list = $("#image-list");
        list.append("<li><img class='" + count + "' src=''></li>");
        $("." + count + "").attr("src",source);
        count++;
    }

    $('[type="file"]').change(function() {
        var file = this.files;

        $.each(file, function(i, filename) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                showUploadedItem(e.target.result, filename.name);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(filename);
        });
    });

$('button').click(function() {      

    var files = $("[type='file']")[0].files;

    $.each(files, function(i, file) {

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('images', file.name, file);

        console.log(formdata);

        $.ajax({
            url :"up.php",
            data:formdata,
            type:"POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        });
    }); 
});
}());
```

In PHP I have this:

```
<?php 
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $_FILES['images']['name']);
?>
```

I modified a bit the code because I found the problem but now when I submit the images I have the problem with the PHP limit file upload and the form data not uploads the files one by one.

EDIT2: The solution that I found was to put and each loop within the click event and within the each I put the ajax call.

Comment: Keep in mind `formdata` does on work on IE, I would suggest you to go with hidden iframe method http://blog.w3villa.com/programming/upload-image-without-submitting-form-works-on-all-browsers/

Comment: It will be used only on chrome

Comment: do you want to submit them all at once or submit one by one?

Comment: Submit them one by one. The unique way that I found was putting and $.each() into the button.click and make the AJAX call for every image in the input file. Also I must create a new FormData() in each iteration

Comment: @pocesar I've updated the code to show you how I did

Comment: and you need to upload them in order or all at once, but in separated contexts?

Comment: I need upload them one by one for now

Answer (score 0):

FormData takes a single file not a list of files. in your code `file` is actually a `FileList`, `filename` is the file

```
formdata.append("images[]", filename);
```

Comment: I tried it but when I select 30 images to upload and I click submit the PHP only uploads 20 images that it's the limit that exists in the php.ini file. For now the unique solution that I found it's to create a new FormData Object into an each loop that I created in the click function, but the problem it's if I put 1000 images the submit will do 1000 ajax calls...

Comment: @Bultack have you heard of FTP or SSH?

Comment: FTP yep, SSH something but I never used it. Why?

Comment: @Bultack Uploading hundreds of files via a form/ajax seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Yep, but the user who will use this could not use a FTP or SSH connection. I tried to do a basic script as blueimp :/